# Can envers audit changes across the entire hierarchy of parent/child tables?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, many-to-many, one-to-many, hibernate-envers

I have seen this question asked on other forms dated back in 2012 but its now 2019 and I am having this same issue with envers. Has anyone figured this out?!?!?

I am reposting this question from here: [envers multi level entity revision howto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033275/envers-multi-level-entity-revision-howto/54777580#54777580)

User have n Contacts. A Contact can have a localized Comment (Comments are shared between Contacts). Java Beans:

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class User {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<Context> contacts;
}

@Audited
@Entity
public class Contact {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
               cascade = {
                          CascadeType.MERGE,
                          CascadeType.PERSIST,
                          CascadeType.REFRESH})
    Comment comment;
}

@Audited
@Entity
public class Comment {
    String de;
    String en;
    String fr;
}
```

If I change the german localization (Comment.de) of a contact (Contact.comment) then this will create a new revision but not for User. If I ask envers for User Revisions I will never see this "Level 2 change" because the relation between User and Contact was not change, only the german string in the Contact Comment was changed.

But I want see in the User History a new Entry (Changed german comment for contact XYZ).

HAS ANYONE SOLVED THIS?

Comment: So you have a unidirectional relationship between `User` and `Contact`?

Comment: Hi there, Yes I do

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am having the same problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [envers multi level entity revision howto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033275/envers-multi-level-entity-revision-howto)

Comment: Please do not duplicate questions. If you want to attract more votes to a question consider offering a bounty.